# Yosemite OS: Turning a kext off and on -- consequences?

Tags: macos, compatibility

Are there consequences to turning a kext on and off repeatedly?

Also, How can I check to make sure a specific kext is already on or off?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how you turn kext on and off instead load and unload.

But, if you want to know current loaded kext's use Terminal.

```
kextstat > ~/Desktop/kexts.txt
```

This will output a text file to your Desktop of currently active kext.

Comment: or just type `kextstat` and read the output!